# apache xampp how to find cause of internal error 500

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xampp

On my PHP website i m getting **Internal Server Error 500**. I dont know what causing error, even not getting any line number or file name which causing error. I want to know the cause of error so can solve it.

I'm using JavaScript to call PHP function and that function includes other PHP file. And finally JavaScript function gets XML data for further processing

I checked the logs available but not found anything. logs path:

> \apche\log

Where error 500 logs are stored?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

By default errors are written to `error.log` in `$xamppdir\apache\logs`. This can be changed in the apache config though.

Directives to look for in the configuration file:

- ErrorLog
- LogLevel
- CustomLog